# $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dy$ with $x\neq 0$

Tags: integration

How would one compute this integral : $\int_{\mathbb{R}} \frac{1}{x^2+y^2}dy$ when $x \neq 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that
$$\int_{\mathbb{R}}\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}=\pi$$
since $\arctan'(y)=\dfrac{1}{1+y^2}$. Use a relevant change of variables to compute your integral.